# search item using sqlQuery C# ASP.NET and display in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, search, gridview

I can't see any data displayed in a gridview.
Can't see any search results.
I'm trying to use sqlparameter.
As you can see, my sqlQuery is a very long one.
If I enter 'card', it should find item_description with 'big card' or 'small card' values. 
Here is my code:

```
searchWord = Request.Cookies["Search"].Value;
searchType = Request.Cookies["Display"].Value;
string sqlQuery;
string custSearch = searchWord;

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
SqlConnection sc = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString());

sqlQuery = "SELECT Player.player_id AS 'ID', Player.fname AS 'First name', "
         +"Player.lname AS 'Last name', Player.sport AS 'Sports',"
         +"Player.position AS 'Position', Player.debut_year AS 'Debut year',"
         +"Player.prof_year AS 'Major year', Player.birth_date AS 'Date of birth'," 
         +"Player.birth_place AS 'Place of birth', Player.team_f AS 'Current team',"
         +"Player.team_s AS 'Past team1', Player.team_t AS 'Past team2',"
         +"Player.living AS 'Death status' " 
         +"FROM Player WHERE (Player.fname LIKE '@SearchPam') "
         +"OR (Player.lname LIKE '@SearchPam') OR (Player.sport LIKE '@SearchPam') "
         +"OR (Player.position LIKE '@SearchPam') OR (Player.team_f LIKE '@SearchPam') "
         +"OR (Player.team_s LIKE '@SearchPam') OR (Player.team_t LIKE '@SearchPam');";
try
{
     sc.Open();
     string result = sqlQuery;
     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(result, sc);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchPam", custSearch);
     SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
     DataSet ds = new DataSet();

     adapter.Fill(ds);

     GridView1.DataSource = ds;
     GridView1.DataBind();
}
catch{...}
finally{sc.Close();}

public string GetConnectionString()
{
    return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
}
```

Comment: You should use ds.Tables[0] instead of only ds

Comment: I think you are missed the % operator. Your statement should be like this `LIKE '%@SearchPam%'`

Comment: I just deleted DataSet ds = new DataSet(); and instead now I switch to use DataTable dt = new DataTable(); instead.                     GridView1.DataSource = dt;
GridView1.DataBind();

Comment: Are you able to see records in QuickWatch in dataset?

Comment: If you are not getting any value in **dataset** or **datatable** then the problem is in your query try executing the same in **SSMS** and see if there's any result also do follow @SankarRaj comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either of the following queries, i think you will get expected output using this:

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM TableA WHERE Col1 LIKE @SearchPam";
.
.
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchPam", "%" + txtSearch.Text + "%");
```

OR

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM TableA WHERE Col1 LIKE '%' + @SearchPam+ '%'";
.
.
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchPam", txtSearch.Text);
```